# Hide and show kendo ui grid column

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there any way to display and hide coloumn onEdit and Add mode. As display in the sample code. I want to display Unit Price on add and edit mode and hide in view mode. Please advise. But the following will shrink the grid. i want to make it still 100%. What event should i use if the user click cancel.

```
@model IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);

    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
    )
     .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound").Edit("onEdit"))
)


<script type="text/javascript">

function onEdit(e) {
var grid = $('#Product').data('kendoGrid');
        if (!e.model.isNew()) {
            grid.showColumn(2);
        }
        else
        {
            grid.showColumn(2);
        }

function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $('#Product').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.hideColumn(2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in `popup` mode hidden columns of the original `grid` are not hidden. If you remove your `onEdit` function it should be enough. You might even remove the `dataBound` and set it to `hidden` in the column initialization:

```
@model IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.ProductViewModel>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Hidden( true );

    })
    .Groupable()
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Grid"))
    )
)
```

Check in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/B2Ses/ how the column `Freight` is hidden in column mode but visible on popup (both for editing and creation).

Answer (score 1):

For other grid properties (toolbar etc.) with .HtmlAttributes function you can use:

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Name("New item").HtmlAttributes(style = ViewData["isThisPropertyAllowed"] }))
```

And in Controller use for example:

```
ViewData["isThisPropertyAllowed"] =  (User.IsInRole("ADMIN")?"":"display:none");
```

Comment: this will only hide the columns not the header and footer

Comment: better to use .Hidden instead of .HTMLAttribute so that it will hide whole column not just items.
.Hidden(Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["isThisPropertyAllowed"]))
you can send "true" or "false"